# Best practise for running many long awaits in an Azure function

Tags: function, azure

I have an Azure function triggered via service bus which basically just does a long await (1 - 4.5 minutes (managed with cancellation token to prevent function timeout and host restarting)).

I want to process as many of these long await messages as I can. (Ideally about 1200 at the same time..)

First I ran my function on an App Service Plan (with Concurrent Calls = 1200), but I think each trigger creates a thread, and 1200 threads causes some issues.

So I decided to run it on Consumption, with Batch Size 32, with the idea what I can avoid creating tons of threads and scale out the consumption function instead when it sees the queue build up.

Unfortunately exactly the opposite happens, the Consumption function will process 32 messages, but never scales out even though the queue has 1000+ items in it. Even worse, some times the function just goes to sleep although there are still many items in the queue.

I feel my best option would be to group work in a message, so instead of 1 message = 1 long await, 1 message could be 100 awaits for example, but my architecture doesn't really allow to me group messages easily (because if some tasks fail but some succeed this is easily managed with dead letters, but with grouping I need to maintain state to track this). Is there an existing way to efficiently have many (independent) long running awaits on an azure function, either consumption or service plan.

Comment: Have you looked at using Durable Functions?

Comment: To use Durable Functions I have to batch my work together which is what I'm trying to avoid. If I have 1000 work items, and 50 fail, currently I will get 50 dead letters which is something I would like to keep.